# SF data entry in journey is not evaluating contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

we have journey running for new contacts, Welcome journey triggered on SF data entry on created /Updated event.
so there are few contacts which did not entered in Journey also not available in DE created by SF data entry we checked that they should enter as they match the entry criteria.
for cross evaluation we checked on connector is working fine so the sync DE getting the contacts.

Journey setting is : No reentry.
AS these are new contacts no chance that they have already entered in Journey.
what could be other possible reason?
Thanks in Advance.

Update: There was backend issue at salesforce where Update action was not able to work and pick proper records.

Comment: When you go to journey history, do you see them with the ContactAttempted status or you don’t see them at all?

Comment: I don't find them at all. As I mentioned above they do not even there in DE created by SF data entry.

Comment: Do you have any other active journeys running right now that work as expected with sf data?

Comment: yes others are running fine as expected.

Comment: That rules out connector issues - in that case I’d assume those contacts did not meet criteria after all but hard to troubleshoot with so little info

Comment: this is something weird! I tried to filter on sync DE and I got those records there with exact same filter's like we have on journey entry, but its not triggered through the journey???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145121/discussion-between-guljar-shaikh-and-zuzannamj).

Comment: maybe when they get updated in CRM, the fields were changed are not the fields listed in primary object entry criteria. To trigger the update, you have to specifically update one or more fields defined in the entry criteria. changing from a false condition to true